# Using tiptap with v-model and <script setup> in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tiptap

I'm trying to use tiptap with Vue.js with the `<script setup>` approach of creating a Single File Component (SFC).

**TextEditor.vue**

```html
<template>
  <editor-content :editor="editor" class="editor" />
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { useEditor, EditorContent } from '@tiptap/vue-3'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'

const props = defineProps({
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  }
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const editor = useEditor({
  content: props.modelValue,
  extensions: [StarterKit],
  onUpdate: ({editor}) => {
    let content = editor.getHTML()
    emit('update:modelValue', content)
  }
})
</script>
```

I then use this component like this:

```html
<template>
  <text-editor v-model="myModel.content" />
</template>
```

This works when `<text-editor>` is loaded *after* `myModel.content` is defined.

However, if `<text-editor>` loads *before* `myModel.content` is set from my database API, then the text content remains blank. From what I understand from looking at the examples in the tiptap docs, I need to somehow use `watch` to update my `editor` when `props.modelValue` is changed using something like this:

```js
watch(() => props.modelValue, (newValue, oldValue) => {
  const isSame = newValue === oldValue
  console.log(`Same: ${isSame}`)
  if (isSame) {
    return
  }
  editor.commands.setContent(newValue, false)
})
```

However, in the snippet above, `editor` is a `ShallowRef` type and doesn't have a reference to `commands` to call `setContent`.

What is the best way to get the above example to work when loading tiptap with the `<script setup>` approach?

Comment: Are your `myModel.content` is a Ref ?

Comment: If it's ok, you can show the editor only when the data is ready by adding a v-if: `<text-editor v-if="myModel.content" v-model="myModel.content" />`.

Comment: You shouldn't compare `newValue === oldValue` as it results to `false` when the change come from the editor (and triggers uselessly `setContent`). It's better to track changes with `editor.value.getHTML() === newValue`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to access the ref actual value with `.value`

```js
editor.value?.commands.setContent('<p>test</p>', false)
```